# Set of products with different types of products and quantity in C# / Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database-design, entity-framework-core

I am kinda new in C# and Entity Framework and trying to make a simple warehouse management system just for training. The problem is I don't know how to make sets of products to work.

I have classes like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Signature { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
}

public class SetOfProducts
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    // Here should be some lines of code that I don't know
}
```

What I am trying to do is:

- Create set of e.g. 3 products: ProductX, ProductY, ProductZ, but these can be with different quantity e.g 2pcs ProductX, 4pcs ProductY,  1pc ProductZ
- Also #1 I will never know how many types of products and their pieces will be in set, so I can't hardcode
- Also #2 When I take off Set of products from stock it should decrease available amount of those type of products from main table of Products.

I've made a lot of searching and only find something called "table association", but without any understandable for me details.

I hope I explained this enough. Please help :P

Comment: You mean an Order? A list of things a customer wants to buy, in a single transaction?

Comment: Not an Order. The set of products prepared by me in the werehouse. For example: You (as a client) can order three individual products ordering them one by one (1pc of tomato, 2pcs of ham, 3psc of bread), instead of that (and this is what I am trying to do) you could order SandwichKit that includes those 3 ingredients in these amounts by one order.

Comment: Seems similar; maybe should have a Kit table and a KitProduct table; 1 Kit:Many KitProduct, 1 Product:Many KitProduct. KitProduct carries qty. one product can be part of many kits. One kit can have many products. Classic M:M, Google how to handle them in EF? Common topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Caius Jard said

> Seems similar; maybe should have a Kit table and a KitProduct table; 1 Kit:Many KitProduct, 1 Product:Many KitProduct. KitProduct carries qty. one product can be part of many kits. One kit can have many products. Classic M:M, Google how to handle them in EF? Common topic

That was a right answer.

In Product model I have

```
public virtual ICollection<ProductSetQuantity>? ProductSetQuantities { get; set; }
```

In ProductSet model:

```
public virtual ICollection<ProductSetQuantity>? ProductSetQuantities { get; set; }
```

And an additional association table table called ProductSetQuantity:

```
    public  class ProductSetQuantity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product? Product { get; set; }

    public int? ProductSetId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductSet? ProductSet { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a collection navigation property:

```
public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

[EF Core Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)